# Php, Regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I got this pattern(I am using php):

```
'/\[link\=((https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?)\]/i'
```

When i search for this string: `http://phpquest.zapto.org/users/register.php`

The matches are(The order is 0-5):

1. `'[link=http://phpquest.zapto.org/users/register.php]'`
2. `'http://phpquest.zapto.org/users/register.php'`
3. `'http://'`
4. `'phpquest.zapto'`
5. `org`
6. `''`

When i replace the `*` with `+` inside the last subpattern like that:

```
'/\[link\=((https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]+)*\/?)\]/i'
```

The matches are(The order is 0-5):

1. `'[link=http://phpquest.zapto.org/users/register.php]'`
2. `'http://phpquest.zapto.org/users/register.php'`
3. `'http://'`
4. `'phpquest.zapto'`
5. `org`
6. `'/users/register.php'`

If anyone can help me understand why is that i will be very thankful, Thank you all and have a nice day.

Comment: `why is that` - Try to specify your question.

Comment: Why aren't you using `parse_url`? Don't reinvent the wheel, we know how they work.

Comment: I may use it i did take a look but i do wanna understand the reason, Thanks

Comment: **This might not be a job for regexes, but for existing tools in your language of choice.**  Regexes are not a magic wand you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings. You probably want to use existing code that has already been written, tested, and debugged.

In PHP, use the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.


Perl: [`URI` module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/).

Ruby: [`URI` module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html).

.NET: ['Uri' class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your comment after i show at Frits van Campen i will use parse_url but i want to understand.

Comment: I would also like an explaination, if it is possible to explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a simpler example is when you compare [this](http://www.regex101.com/r/wE3bE1) to [this](http://www.regex101.com/r/aH8aP6).

The regexes involved are:

```
(a*)*
```

and

```
(a+)*
```

And the test string is `aaaaaa`.

What happens is that after capturing the main group (in the example I provided, the series of `a`'s) it attempts to match more, but cannot. But wait! It can also match nothing, because `*` means 0 or more times!

Therefore, after matching all the `a`'s, it will match and catch a 'nothing' and since only the last captured part is stored, you get '' as result of the capture group.

In `(a+)*`, after matching and catching `aaaaaa`, it cannot match or catch anything more (`+` prevents it to match nothing, as opposed to `*`) and hence, `aaaaaa` is the last match.

Comment: Jerry thanks so much now i got it, Well explained answer thanks again and have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

This can be simplified with the following pattern.

```
/\[link=(https?:\/\/)(([a-z0-9]+\.?)+)((\/[^\/]+)+)\/?\]/i
```

The regex symbol `*` is not greedy, while `+` is. Hence, when using the `+` in the second attempt, all path components are matched and that group is captured; however, in the first attempt with `*`, since you were only capturing the inner `*` group with parenthesis, you matched the un-greedy sample of the `*`, in this case nothing.

Comment: Thank you matt, But can you please explain why the pattern on my question is not showing the last subpattern on * and with + it doe's.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, is it? The author asked "Why does it behave like that?" not "How to make it better"